# Android: NetworkOnMainThreadException not called

Tags: android

I'm familiar with Android development and used to the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception when doing a network call on the UIThread.

However in the following case the IOException is thrown and no `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown.

Code:

```
        try {
            a = mGeo.getFromLocationName("SFO", 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I find this weird.  Shouldn't the network exception (which is a runtime exception) be thrown?

Comment: If `mGeo` is a `Geocoder`, you are not doing network I/O yourself in your own process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check implementation on [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/location/java/android/location/Geocoder.java)  then IOException is the checked exception and is thrown from the code.
for reference I am adding implementation from above link more can be found in comments in implementation

```
public List<Address> getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults) throws IOException {
if (locationName == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("locationName == null");
}
try {
    List<Address> results = new ArrayList<Address>();
    String ex = mService.getFromLocationName(locationName,
        0, 0, 0, 0, maxResults, mParams, results);
    if (ex != null) {
        throw new IOException(ex);
    } else {
        return results;
    }
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "getFromLocationName: got RemoteException", e);
    return null;
}
}
```

NetworkOnMainThreadException is an unchecked exception as it extends RuntimeException, this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) from java documentation may help.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks...that makes a lot of sense.  So it was basically just an API design choice for GeoServices.  I was previously under the impression that Android always knew when a network call was happening and was guaranteed to throw runtime exception in calling process.

Comment: Yes, as CommonsWare said if you are doing network call on your own process then you need to handle the NetworkOnMainThreadException.